# Conditional Matrix: calculate values based on pair of columns

Tags: r, lapply

I have a data frame *df* which looks like

```
  A1  A2  A3
1: 1   0   1
2: 1   1   0
3: 1   0   1
```

and want to create a matrix with all conditional mean-values, where the condition is a "1" in another column.
eg:

1. for A3 conditional on A1 there should be calculated 2/3=0.66 (=> colsum(A3,in rows where A1=1))/colsum(A1))
2. for A1 conditional on A3 there should be calculated 2/2=1.0 (=> colsum(A1,in rows where A3=1)/colsum(A3))
3. for A2 conditional on A1 there should be calculated 1/3=1.0 (=> colsum(A2,in rows where A1=1))/colsum(A1))

I managed my problem with following code:

```
    col_names <- names(df)
    mat = matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)
    for (i in 1:3){
      for (j in 1:3){
        mat[j,i]=mean(df[ get(col_names[j]) == 1, ][[col_names[i]]],na.rm = TRUE)
      }
    }
    colnames(mat) <- col_names
    rownames(mat) <- col_names
```

*mat* looks then like it should be (here with fractions):

```
    A1   A2   A3
A1 3/3  1/1  2/2
A2 1/3  1/1  0/2
A3 2/3  0/1  2/2
```

Unfortunately, this code is very slowly. Is there a way (maybe with lapply ...) to speed it up? I don't get rid of the conditions (==1)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#DATA
df1 = structure(list(A1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L),
                     A2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L),
                     A3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df1
#  A1 A2 A3
#1  1  0  1
#2  1  1  0
#3  1  0  1

sapply(1:NCOL(df1), function(i) sapply(1:NCOL(df1), function(j) {
    sum((df1[,j])[df1[,i] == 1])/sum(df1[,i])
    #paste0(sum((df1[,j])[df1[,i] == 1]),"/",sum(df1[,i]))
}))
#          [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 1.0000000    1    1
#[2,] 0.3333333    1    0
#[3,] 0.6666667    0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
# convert to matrix
mat <- as.matrix(df)

# calculate numerator
numer <- matrix(NA, 3, 3)
for(j in 1:ncol(df)) { numer[,j] <- colSums(mat*mat[,j]) }

# calculate denominator
denom <- matrix(apply(mat, 2, sum, na.rm=T), 3, 3, byrow=T)

# divide numer/denom and fix NAs and Infs
result <- numer / denom
result[is.na(result)|is.infinite(result)] <- 0

result
```